# Android equivalent to apple's MDM

Tags: android, ios, mdm

I heard Apple have an MDM feature built in the iOS, which enables a server to send a set of MDM commands to its registered devices.

My question - is there an equivalent of such a thing in Android.
Maybe through GCM?

Or put in different words: Do I have to write a client app on the device to manage it remotely?

Thanks!

Edit: 
What I need actually is just the ability for basic queries about the phone: hardware, os version, operator... stuff like that. Maybe also a list of installed apps.
By MDM I mean Mobile-Device-Management. But all I need actually are the above mentioned get-methods.

Comment: What specifically do you want to do? Try DDMS, it comes with the android SDK and is built into the ADT plugin for eclipse ide.

Comment: I doubt too many of the people on this Tag know what MDM is. Could you explain in more general terms?

Comment: @RaghavSood what do you mean "this Tag"? I have 3 tags. You mean I needed to put mdm tag first? I didn't know the order matters... thanks.

Comment: I meant the Android tag. A lot of the users here will only monitor this tag, although your question will be seen on all three. The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Android has multitasking, iOS does not. With Android you can write an application which can manage a device directly. iOS does not allow this and you will need to utilize the MDM framework provided by them. This has limitations that cannot be circumvented.

There is C2DM which you can utilize like APNS to reach out to the device, but this will still speak to the client app. This has now been replaced with GCM.

Comment: Thanks! that's the direction I took - totally different approach for android vs. iOS. Thanks for verifying!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Android do have equivalents to Apple's MDM.

There are many [Mobile Device Management solutions](http://www.mobiledevicemanagement.io/mobile-device-management-comparison/) available in the market today that could do everything Apple's MDM does.

An MDM can provide information on everything that you have mentioned and it can do a lot more. It can provide reports on every tasks and locations too.